# Access jQuery function parameter to other part of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function and it has a parameter where I load a list of objects. The point is that I want to access this parameter in other part of my jsp page.

```
<script>
    function nacitajProjekty() {
        var projekty

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/jira-server/all-projects",
            async: false,
            success: function (returnData) {
                projekty = returnData;
                console.log(projekty)

            }
        });
    }
</script>

 <label for="multiselect">Projekty</label>
        <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Vyberte projekt...">
        </select>
            <script>

                    $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
                        dataSource: I WANT TO ACCESS VARIABLE "projekty" here,
                        dataTextField: "name",
                        dataTextValue: "id"
                    });

            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this variable out side the function then this variable will be accesible globly

```
<script>
    var projekty;
    function nacitajProjekty() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/jira-server/all-projects",
            async: false,
            success: function (returnData) {
                projekty = returnData;
                console.log(projekty)

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @MartinDurco Check using console. `projekty` before `$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({` declaration. Check `projekty` is `undefind` or blank